# Colocar o input no final do container com Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite, estou tentando colocar esse input no final desse container com bootstrap, mas não consigo de jeito nenhum.
Eu preciso que esse input de search fique no final dessa row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>Teste</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar nome..." class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode tranquilamente tem apenas duas `col-4` dentro de uma `row`. E para colocar uma de cada lado do *container* vc pode colocar `ml-auto` na `col` do `input` ou colocar `justify-content-between` direto na `row`. Consulte a documentação oficial do Flex no Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Opção `ml-auto`

```
<div class="col-4 ml-auto">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar nome..." class="form-control ">
</div>
```

Ou com `class="row justify-content-between"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h1>Teste</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar nome..." class="form-control ">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Julio, apenas acrescente o código float-right em sua class. Obviamente vc precisará trabalhar o tamanho do seu campo. Adaptei pra vc.

Segue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <h1>Teste</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar nome..." class="form-control float-right" style="width:200px;">
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```